# .toggle() function not functioning correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a register/login overlay for users although when trying to use the JQuery .toggle() I have no luck. I can't see any obvious issues and any minor tweaks I've made have been unsuccessful.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Photography</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/style.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/bootstrap.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="nav">
        <div class="nav-container">
            <b>Photography</b><beta>BETA</beta>
            <div class="nav-options">
                <a href="" id="toggle-reg"><i class="icon-user"></i>Register</a>
                <ul class="register">
                        Username
                        <input type="text"/>
                        Password
                        <input type="text"/>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary">Sign in</button><button class="btn btn-danger">Forgot?</button>
                </ul>
                <a href="">User CP</a>
                <a href="">Images</a>
                <a href="">Home</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.register').hide();
        $('#toggle-reg').click(function() {
            $('.register').toggle(slow);
        });
    });

    </script>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
     .register {
    background: #fff;
    padding: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 220px;
    border: 2px solid #f1f1f1;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #f1f1f1;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px#f1f1f1;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #f1f1f1;
    top: 50px;
 }
```

Comment: What exactly is happening or not happening?

Comment: The list does not display upon clicking the "Register" link. Changed to toggle('slow') to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

Check it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Photography</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/style.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/bootstrap.css"/>
    <style>
            .register {
    background: #fff;
    padding: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 220px;
    border: 2px solid #f1f1f1;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #f1f1f1;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px#f1f1f1;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #f1f1f1;
    top: 50px;
 }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="nav">
        <div class="nav-container">
            <b>Photography</b><beta>BETA</beta>
            <div class="nav-options">
                <a href="javascript:;" id="toggle-reg"><i class="icon-user"></i>Register</a>
                <ul class="register">
                        Username
                        <input type="text"/>
                        Password
                        <input type="text"/>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary">Sign in</button><button class="btn btn-danger">Forgot?</button>
                </ul>
                <a href="">User CP</a>
                <a href="">Images</a>
                <a href="">Home</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.register').hide();
        $('#toggle-reg').click(function() {
            $('.register').toggle('slow');
        });
    });

    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `.toggle()` with an undefined *variable* called `slow`:

```
$('.register').toggle(slow);
```

You need to pass the *string* `"slow"`:

```
$('.register').toggle("slow");
```

And you may need to cancel the default click behaviour and/or change the link's `href=""` to `href="#"`:

```
    $('#toggle-reg').click(function(e) {
        $('.register').toggle("slow");
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/PDaej/1